# What is the cleanest way to share a TextBox.AppendText() method across classes?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a Controller object that launches a simple Windows Form. Inside the Form is a text box to which I want to log my program's output. Right now, I have a Controller method that calls a method in the Form which then puts the logged message in the text box. Then I reference the Controller when creating the objects I want to log stuff and call "Controller.Log(str)", but this approach seems dirty to me.

In what way would you guys tackle this problem, and keep the code loosely coupled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a question that suits better in programmers stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a Listener structure similar to the .net Trace classes. The UI can pass a callback into a centralised logging service (perhaps itself created through an IOC like Unity) and the logger sends its message to that centralised logging service. Nice thing there is that there can be many readers of the message allowing both UI and disk based logging at the same time, with no added complexity.

The .net Trace architecture is a good place to start. I can call Trace.WriteLine anywhere in my code without coupling to the listener.